# Return a value from a block stored in a Dictionary? EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc)

Tags: objective-c

```
[dictionary setObject: ^int{
        //some code
        int value = 1;
        return value;
    }
            forKey:@"my code block"];
```

To evaluate it somewhere else I use this:

```
typedef int (^storedBlock)();

int result = ((storedBlock)[dictionary objectForKey:@"my code block"])();
```

Whenever I hit the last line I get `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc)` I don't get it, is my syntax wrong? Is this an async issue with the stack and frame do I need to put a copy of that block in the dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Block_copy(blockToBeStored)` before setting object in `dictionary` 
and 
`Block_release(blockToBeStored)` after that

Comment: Hmm... I'm using ARC so that necessary? What it s the exact syntax with my code? Block_copy((__bridge int)^int{
        //some code
        int value = 1;
        return value;
    })

Comment: @unmircea It is still likely necessary in this case because the compiler does not automatically copy the block on insertion into the dictionary.   A block (sometimes) starts on the stack and `Block_copy()` moves it to the heap.